# How to find annualized return in a data set containing 30 stocks in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a dataset containing the closing price of 30 stocks. I have to find the average annualized return and volatility of each stock. I don't have a problem with the formula, I can't seem to be able to formulate how to iterate over each stock and then find it's closing price, and then save each closing price in a different column.

What I have tried:

I have tried to iterate over the columns, and then return the columns, and then assign the function to a variable like:

```
def get_columns(df):
    for columns in df:
        return columns

namesOfColumn = get_columns(df)
```

When I check the type of **namesOfColumn**, it returns **str**, and when I check the content of the string, it is the title of the first column in my dataset.

I have also tried

```
def get_columns(df):
    for columns in df:
        column = df[columns]
        for column in df[columns]:
            stock = column
            returns = df[stock].pct_change()
```

My current dataframe looks like

```
  A Close  B Close 
0 823.45   201.9
1 824.90   198.9
2 823.60   198.3
```

A & B are the name of the companies.

There are total 30 columns like this,and each columns has around 240 values.

```
  A Return  B Return 
0 xxxx.xx   xxxx.xx
```

I want my output to look like this
I want to find the annual return of each stock, and then save the return in a dictionary, and then convert that dictionary to a dataframe.

Comment: Can we see the structure of the dataframe and an example of your expected output, please?

Comment: I have updated my question with both of these things, please take a look.

Comment: `df.pct_change()` can already give you the change between the current and a prior element. Can you provide the formula or expected output so that others can understand what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the index of your dataframe is in datetime format you could just use pandas resample (below I am resampling it yearly - please refer to pandas resample documentation for more info) and do the following:

```
(1 + df.pct_change()).resample('Y').prod() - 1
```

Since, it looks like your dataframe is not indexed with pandas datetime, you will have to reindex it first (and then apply the code shown above) as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
initial_date = '20XX-XX-XX' #set here the initial date of your dataframe   
end_date = '20XX-XX-XX' #set here the end date of your dataframe
df.set_index(pd.date_range(start=initial_date, end=end_date) inplace=True)
```